# Do native _SEPARATOR in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking at some code that uses `PATH_SEPARATOR`. I don't think this constant is explicitly defined anywhere but I could be wrong. Does anyone know if this is a native constant in PHP, and do other similar separators exist without needing to define? I'm trying to see if I can use LINE_SEPARATOR, PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR, and such but nothing worked. How do I define these if I need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation will yield all the answers you are looking for:

- [Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)
- [Magic Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) - "Constants" who's value changes depending on where they are used...

So, looking there,

- `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` - The directory separator for the current OS (`/` for Linux, `\` for Windows, etc)
- `PATH_SEPARATOR` - You already saw that.
- `PHP_EOL` - The system's new line format (`\n` for Linux, `\r\n` for Windows, etc)
- `PHP_OS` - The current operating system.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of all PHP native constants here: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php]
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php . PATH_SEPARATOR is on the list

Answer (score 2):

PATH_SEPARATOR is the character that separates paths in include paths (typically a ';'). For an example, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php.